# Parse an XML string in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have this XML string result and i need to get the values in between the tags. But the data type of the XML is string.

```
  final = "  <Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>80601</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>80318</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>167187008</Job></Table>

    <Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>71115</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><Experiment>6794</Experiment><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>71105</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>16799006</Job></Table> "
```

This is my code sample

```
root = ET.fromstring(final)
print root
```

And this is the error i am receiving :

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Ive tried using ET.fromstring. But with no luck.

Comment: What is `ET` exactly in your code?

Comment: Please give your code sample, that will help others to understand what u are trying?

Comment: I edited the question @har07

Comment: Your XML is malformed. It has to have exactly one top level element.

Comment: i see. so i just need to add the <xml> </xml> ? @MaciejLach

Comment: Yes or better to something more relevant root element e.g. `Tables`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your XML is malformed. It has to have exactly one top level element. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element):

> Each XML document has exactly one single root element. It encloses all
>   the other elements and is therefore the sole parent element to all the
>   other elements. ROOT elements are also called PARENT elements.

Try to enclose it within additional tag (e.g. `Tables`) and than parse with ET:

```
xmlData = '''<Tables>
<Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>80601</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>80318</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>167187008</Job></Table>
<Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>71115</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><Experiment>6794</Experiment><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>71105</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>16799006</Job></Table>
</Tables>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring(xmlData)

for table in xml.getiterator('Table'):
    for child in table:
        print child.tag, child.text
```

Since Python 2.7 `getiterator('Table')` should be replaced with [`iter('Table')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter):

```
for table in xml.iter('Table'):
    for child in table:
        print child.tag, child.text
```

This produces:

```
Claimable false
MinorRev 80601
Operation 530600 ION MILL
HTNum 162
WaferEC 80318
HolderType HACARR
Job 167187008
Claimable false
MinorRev 71115
Operation 530600 ION MILL
Experiment 6794
HTNum 162
WaferEC 71105
HolderType HACARR
Job 16799006
```

Comment: Perfect answer, though I suggest the OP to change the root tag name to something more relevant to the OP than <xml>.

Comment: @BhargavRao: as suggested, I changed the tag to `Tables`.

Comment: Thanks for that change. These small things are side effects of working in industry. Cheers.

Comment: im receiving this error 'AttributeError: _ElementInterface instance has no attribute 'iter'' im using python 2.7.3 @MaciejLach

Comment: [`Element.iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iter) is available since 2.7. You can try to replace it with [`Element.getiterator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.getiterator).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you tried `node.attrib`, try `node.text` instead to get the string value (also see [Parsing XML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml) in the Python docs):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml_string = "<Table><Claimable>false</Claimable><MinorRev>80601</MinorRev><Operation>530600 ION MILL</Operation><HTNum>162</HTNum><WaferEC>80318</WaferEC><HolderType>HACARR</HolderType><Job>167187008</Job></Table>"

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)

for child in root:
    print child.tag, child.text
```

This should give you the

```
Claimable false
MinorRev 80601
Operation 530600 ION MILL
HTNum 162
WaferEC 80318
HolderType HACARR
Job 167187008
```

Comment: This is what i tried at first, but i needed to add a top level tag for this to work. Thank you! @adrianus